# How to kill the demonized fusion passenger rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Using daemonize option, I execute the rails app with phusion passenger as a daemon.

```
bundle exec passenger start --port 8000 --user ubuntu --daemonize
```

How to kill the daemonized app?

I have four processes running, but I think there might be a better way to kill all the processes to stop the daemon.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing only the master process automatically kills all the other processes.

From the screen capture, `kill -9 5702` will kill all the running processes. Even with passenger, the passenger.IP.pid file contains the pid so that you can use to kill the process.

With `passenger-status` or `passenger-memory-status`, I can get the id so that I can kill the process.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-63-19 public> sudo passenger-status
Version : 5.0.21
Date    : 2015-11-06 05:54:30 +0000
Instance: GbUcQO1V (nginx/1.8.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.21)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 1
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 1
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/ubuntu/webapp/rails/passenger-ruby-rails-demo/public (development):
  App root: /home/ubuntu/webapp/rails/passenger-ruby-rails-demo
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 3355    Sessions: 0       Processed: 8       Uptime: 4s
    CPU: 10%     Memory  : 61M     Last used: 3s ago
```